# Configuration section with sub element and variable attributes

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

Is it possible for .NET configuration sections to implement a structure like this:

```
<myFramework
    myAttr1="myValue1"
    myAttr2="myValue2"
    ...
>
    <hosting class="My.Framework.Hosting1"
             hosting1Attr1="value"
             hosting1Attr2="value"/>
</myFramework>
```

Where the hosting *class* may vary, and therefore the required attributes would vary as well, i.e. somebody else would configure the framework with a different `hosting` element:

```
    <hosting class="My.Framework.Hosting2" hosting2Only1Attr="value"/>
```

What's the proper way to implement that? I've only seen the concept of a provider model, however, it looks like providers enable the user to configure multiple hosting elements?!